# Reinstall microsoft Edge after removing its folder

Tags: windows-10, reinstall, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge is really unstable on my PC. Hanged like a couple of times a day...  I deleted the Microsft Edge folder entirely. I deleted it so I would be able to install it back but I run into problems.

When I try to install it back using the following command:

```
 Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" -Verbose}
```

I get an error

> ```
> Add-AppxPackage : Cannot find path 'C:\AppXManifest.xml' because it does not exist. At line:1 char:68
> ```
>
> + ...  | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.I ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\AppXManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], ItemNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

any ideas?

Comment: Are you running it from C:\Users\youruser?

Comment: Get-AppXPackage doesn't work with Edge as Edge isn't installed that way.

Comment: ok...f*** Edge then;) I realy wanted to give it a go. MS plays it wroong